# slick slider пока карусель не загрузилась показывать preloader

Tags: jquery, плагин, slick.js

использую [данный плагин](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) для слайдов и каруселей, при загрузки страницы в каруселях появляются все картинки и на мгновение плывет сайт, как сделать чтоб пока карусель полностью не загрузилась показывать preloader, после убирать preloader и показывать карусель? Другой плагин просьба не предлагать. Пробовал делать через событие `init` но тогда карусель не знает какую ширину(или высоту в зависимости от направления карусели) ставить(( пример прилагаю(поставил `setTimeout` чтобы имитировать загрузку страницы).

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
    $('.prod__slider').on('init', function () {
    $('.prod__slider').removeClass('hide');
    $('.prod__slider-wrp .preloader').removeClass('show');
  });
 
  $('.prod__slider').slick({
    vertical: true,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    speed: 800,
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    infinite: false,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1030,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 700,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  } , 1000);

});
```

```css
.preloader{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block!important;
}
.hide{
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod__slider-wrp">
  <div class="preloader show">Прелоадер</div> 
  <div class="prod__slider hide">
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен плагин: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Так используется:

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded
});
```

Рабочий код:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.prod__slider').imagesLoaded(function() {

    $('.prod__slider').on('init', function() {
      $('.prod__slider').removeClass('hide');
      $('.prod__slider-wrp .preloader').removeClass('show');
    });

    $('.prod__slider').slick({
      vertical: true,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      speed: 800,
      dots: false,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      infinite: false,
      responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 1030,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 700,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.preloader {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block!important;
}

.hide {
  visible: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod__slider-wrp">
  <div class="preloader show">Прелоадер</div>
  <div class="prod__slider hide">
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
    <div class="slide-item"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x100/" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я поправил еще `.hide {visible: none!important;}` а то слайдер криво вставал